# Prestashop : Display simple page in Admincontroller (without ObjectModel)

Tags: module, prestashop, templating

I want to create a simple page in Prestashop back-office. I don't need any ObjectModel.

I've created a new admin Tab. My problem is in AdminController.

You can see the following code : the variables are not transmitted to the template file. I don't understand how to do it.

```
class AdminAzertyController extends AdminController
{

    public function initContent()
    {

        parent::initContent();

        // Le template smarty

        $tpl_path = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ .'paniersdegout/views/templates/admin/view.tpl';
        $tpl = $this->context->smarty->createTemplate($tpl_path, $this->context->smarty);
        $content = $tpl->fetch();      
        $this->context->smarty->assign('content', $content);

        // Le passage de variable
        $this->context->smarty->assign('test', 'test');

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are fetching the template content before assigning variable to that template.

Comment: You should pass variables before fetching. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To render custom tpl file in the custom controller, you can use smarty to assign content.

For example, if you have to render customtemplate.tpl file of custom module.

```
 public function initContent() {

        parent::initContent();

       $content = $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . 'custommodule/views/templates/admin/customtemplate.tpl');

        $this->context->smarty->assign(
                array(
                    'content' => $this->content . $content,
                )
        );
}
```